# DB Mocking in one Go test case is interfering with other test case

Tags: go, datadog, go-sqlmock

I have two Go test cases as shown below that test a gRPC function called `MyEndpoint`.

`MyEndpoint` is supposed to succeed when the database row it selects has Field1 == "A" and return an error otherwise.

I'm mocking out the database with the [go-sqlmock package from Data-dog](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock).

```
package mypackage_test

import (
    "github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)


type MyEntity struct {
    Id                     sql.NullInt32 `db:"id"`  
    Field1                 sql.NullString `db:"field1"`
    Field2                 sql.NullString `db:"field2"`
    Field3                 sql.NullString `db:"field3"`
}

var Columns = []string{
    "id",
    "field_1",
    "field_2",
    "field_3"
}



var dbRow = []driver.Value{int32(999), "A", "B", "C"]


func TestMyTestA(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Verify MyEndpoint Fails when mocked Database row has Field1 != A", func(t *testing.T) {
        api, err := getMyAPI()
        require.Nil(t, err)
        defer api.Close()

        api.DBMock.ExpectBegin()
        api.DBMock.MatchExpectationsInOrder(false)

        modifiedDBRow := dbRow
        modifiedDBRow[0] = "Z"
        api.DBMock.ExpectQuery("SELECT").
            WithArgs(int32(999)).WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows(Columns).AddRow(modifiedDBRow...))
        api.DBMock.ExpectCommit()
        
        _, err = ... // Call MyEndpoint with parameter Id: int32(999)
        api.DBMock.ExpectClose()
        require.NotNil(t, err)
    })
}

func TestMyTestB(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Verify MyEndpoint succeeds when mocked Database row has Field1 == A", func(t *testing.T) {
        api, err := getMyAPI()
        require.Nil(t, err)
        defer api.Close()

        api.DBMock.ExpectBegin()
        api.DBMock.MatchExpectationsInOrder(false)

        api.DBMock.ExpectQuery("SELECT").
            WithArgs(int32(999)).WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows(Columns).AddRow(dbRow...))
        api.DBMock.ExpectCommit()
        
        _, err = ... // Call MyEndpoint with parameter Id: int32(999)
        api.DBMock.ExpectClose()
        require.Nil(t, err)
    })
}
```

When I run these two test cases individually, they both pass.

But when I run them together, `TestMyTestB` fails because it thinks Field1 == "Z".
So clearly `TestMyTestA` is interfering with `TestMyTestB`. Why?

It seems that the mocking done in `TestMyTestA` case is still in effect when it gets to `TestMyTestB` and the mocking I'm doing in `TestMyTestB` case is completely ignored.

How can I mock these two test cases out independently of one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of an incorrect assignment to `modifiedDBRow` slice in your first test. Remember that a slice does not store any data, it just describes a section of an underlying array.

So when you modified `modifiedDBRow` in the first test, you've inherently modified the underlying array containing value at `[0]`, from `A` to `Z`, which persists when you read the `dbRow` in your next test. Either reset the value at the end of the first test or have a different set of variables to use across tests.

Comment: Thank u. That worked. I did: `modifiedDBRow := make([]driver.Value, len(dbRow)); copy(modifiedDBRow, dbRow); modifiedDBRow[0] = "Z"` This way, the underlying data is unchanged. So even if the test case aborts early, I don't have to worry about the cleanup being skipped.

Comment: Also see [Why can't I duplicate a slice with `copy()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30182538/5291015)