# What's the Go Equivalent of Java's System.arraycopy()?

Tags: java, arrays, go, slice

Is there any Golang equivalent for Java's `java.lang.System.arraycopy()`?

```
arraycopy(Object source_arr, int sourcePos, Object dest_arr, int destPos, int len)
```

To copy a source array from a specific beginning position to the destination array from the mentioned position. Number of arguments to be copied are decided by `len` argument.
The components at `source_Position` to `source_Position + length – 1` are copied to destination array from `destination_Position` to `destination_Position + length – 1`.

Comment: Use https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy with https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions

Answer (score 8):

You may use the builtin [`copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) function.

```
func copy(dst, src []Type) int
```

It only takes 2 arguments: the destination and source slices, but you may use [slice expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) to specify the "missing" parameters, because `copy()` copies no more elements than what's available in the source or what can fit in the destination (see [Why can't I duplicate a slice with `copy()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182538/why-cant-i-duplicate-a-slice-with-copy/30182622#30182622)).

```
src := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
dst := make([]int, len(src))

sourcePos := 2
destPos := 3
length := 4

copy(dst[destPos:], src[sourcePos:sourcePos+length])

fmt.Println(dst)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/4p4l1jpdnLF)):

```
[0 0 0 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0]
```

Another variant is to add `length` to the `destPos`:

```golang
copy(dst[destPos:destPos+length], src[sourcePos:])
```